# Capturing windows XP localhost TCP traffic

Tags: networking, windows-xp, winsock, wireshark, winpcap

I have done a fair amount of reading on this subject - capturing windows xp localhost TCP traffic.

There seem to be a couple of methods:

1/Using RawCap.exe wont work as windows XP handles localhost not through the normal network stack

2/Using a tool like SocketSniff which will look at winsock calls for a particular process (I may try this)

3/Using proxocket dlls to output a cap file for all winsock traffic for a particular application (May not work depending on version of the application or version of windows.

4/Wireshark wont work in this scenario for the same kind of reason that RawCap.exe wont work

I have read in detail this article on wireshark https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback and my question references this section:

So let's say I decide to install a windows loopback adapter.
Next I need to do this :

```
    1. go to MS Loopback adapter properties, set IP 10.0.0.10, MASK 255.255.255.0
2. ipconfig /all and look at the MAC-ID for your new adapter.
3. arp -s 10.0.0.10 <MAC-ID>
4. route add 10.0.0.10 10.0.0.10 mask 255.255.255.255
5. to test: "telnet 10.0.0.10"
```

Now there is something things I dont understand which I would like explained about this sequence of steps. I have an application I want to watch which makes calls to 127.0.0.1 or 'localhost'.

1. I install my MS Loopback adapter, set its IP and Mask.
2. I then grab the MAc address.
3. I then via arp add a static cache entry so 10.0.0.10 resolves to the physical device.
4. I then add a route from 10.0.0.10 to itself, 10.0.0.10

Now at this point surely capturing on this MS Loopback adapter still wont pickup 127.0.0.1 or localhost will it? It would only pick that up if I had my application pointing at 10.0.0.10 as 'localhost'?

Can somebody please clarify - perhaps my understanding is incorrect and it indeed would work??

Answer (score 2):

I decided to try SocketSniff - and it solved my problem entirely - it picked up the calls the application I wanted to monitor was making and I was able to continue happily programming after that!